# [Apple M1]: I got No registered 'RngReadAndSkip' OpKernel for 'GPU' devices compatible with node {{node RngReadAndSkip}} . Registered: device='CPU'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, apple-m1

this is my code

```
random = tf.random.Generator.from_seed(42)
random = random.normal(shape=(2,2))
```

but i got this error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: No registered 'RngReadAndSkip' 
OpKernel for 'GPU' devices compatible with node {{node RngReadAndSkip}}. Registered: device='CPU'
```

Answer (score 15):

It happens because some TF/Keras high-level methods are not implemented in tensorflow-metal. You can try this workaround:

```
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    ...  # your code which need RngReadAndSkip low-level method here
```

And next you can do other stuff normally (with GPU).

Hope, Apple will fix it someday (and their another tons of bugs too, lmao)

Comment: I faced the same problem, your solution worked, also worked the next solution, updating tensorflow-metal to 0.5.1 version.

Answer (score 1):

As answered in another Question, however it took me so long to get a solution that I thought worth sharing here.

As advised in [apple developer webpage](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698217), RngReadAndSkip is registered on the GPU in tensorflow-metal==0.5.1

I upgraded from tensorflow-metal 0.5 to tensorflow-metal 0.5.1 and now it works.

Also, I followed the [instructions provided by apple](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/) by aligning the versions as per table.

When following instructions provided by apple, I was getting higher tensor flow-macos and tensorflow-metal versions, and I had to downgrade to listed versions on the table.

[image: Releases versions]

I also mess around with python version, from 3.10 to 3.8, but not sure that did anything tho.

I hope it helps.